# What if the number of 0x0c is odd in a heap spraying that uses 0x0c0c0c0c?

Tags: security, x86, heap-memory

I can understand why 0x0c0c0c0c is used in a heap spray.

But it takes two bytes to act as a "NOP" (0x0c0c means or al,0x0c).

So what if the number of 0x0c between 0x0c0c0c0c and the address of shellcode is odd? It seems that the last 0x0c will use the first byte of the shellcode, and thus shellcode will not work.

So should I add another one-byte instruction like 0x55 between the 0x0c string and the shellcode?

Comment: If you're heap-spraying shellcode, why not use 0x90909090 (nop; nop; nop; nop) instead? What you spray with will always depend on your needs.

Comment: @nneonneo 0x0c0c0c0c is not only a "NOP" sled before your shellcode, it is also a pointer to the heap you have(to itself). But 0x90909090 is not a userland address. So, it is more reliable to use 0x0c0c0c0c.

Comment: Ah. Well, in that case, you should keep in mind that most heaps are minimally 4-byte aligned. Therefore, your spray will have a deterministic offset mod 4, so you shouldn't run into this misalignment issue in practice.

Comment: So the start address of a heap ends with "00" in binary?@nneonneo

Comment: Heap allocations are typically aligned to 4- or 8-byte boundaries, since they have to be aligned to hold any fundamental type. Therefore, object addresses will always end in 00 binary (i.e. end in 0, 4, 8 or c in hex).

Comment: Oops, it seems my teacher had told me this. ai..... Well, Thank you.